# MutationObserver looping on new nodes

Tags: javascript, dom, mutation-observers

What I'm trying to do here is to highlight some textnode by making them a "span" element. And I would it to work on newly added nodes as well when new message/comment loads. However, I found MutationObserver keeps finding newly added node. Perhaps it is because `doSomething` creates new node and it will be re-discovered by MutationObserver. How do I keep this from happening? Not sure if I should put MutationObserver inside EventListener but it doesnot seem to be working outside of it.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var allTextNodes = textNodesUnder(document.body);
    doSomething(allTextNodes);

    // Select the node that will be observed for mutations
    const targetNode = document.body;

    // Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
    const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

    // Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
    const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
        function scanning(el) {
            // el.style.visibility = "hidden";
            var newTextNodes = textNodesUnder(el);
            doSomething(newTextNodes);
        }
    };

    // Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
    const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

    // Start observing the target node for configured mutations
    observer.observe(targetNode, config); 
    //observer.disconnect(); //will not work if disconnect here
});

function doSomething(node) {
    var newItem = document.createElement("SPAN");
    newItem.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(node.textContent);
    newItem.appendChild(textnode);
    node.replaceWith(newItem); 
}
```

Comment: Just a thought can’t you add some class or data attributes in span tag and ignore that in your callback

Comment: Disconnect the observer before doSomething, then observe again.

Comment: The `callback` seems to do nothing here..., maybe you can post a working code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MutationObserver` callback gets called **every time you change the contents of the node**, *including the times that you do so within the callback itself.* Before making changes within the callback, call `observer.disconnect()`, then reconnect using `observe` after making your changes:

```
const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    function scanning(el) {
        observer.disconnect();
        // el.style.visibility = "hidden";
        var newTextNodes = textNodesUnder(el);
        doSomething(newTextNodes);
        observer.observe(targetNode, config);
    }
};
```